# How should I be using Access-Control-Allow-Headers?

Tags: django, cors, django-cors-headers

I'm building an backend in Django that accepts requests from other domains, so I'm using django-cors-headers to handle CORS. I'm hitting a snag with one of the outside domains hitting my backend, though, because their request code a) sets withCredentials and b) has some extra headers in the request.

Both of these should be irrelevant to them being able to hit my backend, but I get the expected errors of `Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' header in the response is '' which must be 'true'` and `Request header field [field_name] is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.` Some other stackoverflow posts pointed me to `Access-Control-Allow-Credentials = 'true'` for the first, and `Access-Control-Allow-Headers = '*'` for the second, but I couldn't find much on what best practices are.

What I'm trying to figure out is

1. Is it safe to set both of these flags? There are other headers included in the request that handle authentication via tokens, so I'm not sure if there's much security risk here
2. Should I instead tell my users that my backend disallows credentials and other headers (because they're not necessary to the code working)?
3. The docs for Access-Control-Allow-Headers specify `‘The value “*” only counts as a special wildcard value for requests without credentials (requests without HTTP cookies or HTTP authentication information). In requests with credentials, it is treated as the literal header name “*” without special semantics. Note that the Authorization header can’t be wildcarded and always needs to be listed explicitly.’` Am I reading that right thinking that I won't actually be able to set both `Access-Control-Allow-Credentials = true` AND `Access-Control-Allow-Headers = '*'`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. See my response to your 3rd point.
2. Yes. Your server, your rules.
3. Setting both `Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true` and `Access-Control-Allow-Headers: *` is never useful:

- For security reasons, [browsers that support the wildcard](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Allow-Headers#browser_compatibility) in `Access-Control-Allow-Headers` [treat the `*` value literally in the case of credentialed requests](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Allow-Headers#directives).
- Browsers that don't support the wildcard in `Access-Control-Allow-Headers` always treat the `*` value literally.

Comment: That all makes sense and tracks with what I was figuring, thanks!